# canvas: bind photo into the frame

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Good day!

I have a problem with merging canvas images. This questions will be mark as reply I think but I didn't find solution for my problem.

So this the deal:
Get 3 canvas - 1 and 2 are images(must be hidden i think), 3 - merged canvas. 1 is a **frame**, 2 is a **photo**, photo must be *under* frame (at css I could make it with `z-index`).

Html:

```
<div class="container">

    <canvas id="first" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

    <canvas id="second" width="200" height="200"></canvas>

    <canvas id="third" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

</div>
```

JS:

```
var imgFirst = document.getElementById("first");
ctx1 = imgFirst.getContext('2d');
pic1 = new Image();
pic1.src = "http://www.deftune.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/thexx-400x400.jpg";


var imgSecond = document.getElementById("second");
ctx2 = imgSecond.getContext('2d');
pic2 = new Image();
pic2.src = "http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png";

var imgThird = document.getElementById('third');
ctx3 = imgThird.getContext('2d');
pic1.onload = function() {
    pic2.onload = function() {
        ctx3.drawImage(pic1, 0, 0, 400, 400);
        ctx3.drawImage(pic2, 100, 100, 200, 200);
    };
};
```

I've got jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/hh6ovneq/3/ but it not works

Comment: You should pass a reference to an image to `ctxn.drawImage`, i.e. `ctx1.drawImage( pic1, 0,0,400,400 )`, http://jsfiddle.net/hh6ovneq/2/

Comment: @pawel, yes, my bad. fixed, but still doesn't work

Comment: I think you should be using it differently - turn the two image reference canvasses into just img tafg and use drawImage with those will make you job easier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things that could simplify your code a lot. First of, since you are only loading image resources, use the `img` tag instead. Then create a callback function and trigger it when both images have loaded.

Since I am unclear what your photo is and what your frame is I currently use the inversed order that you had, but just switching the two `drawImage` functions should switch their order (or z-index, hopwever you want to describe it). Because your top image doesn't have transparent values, though, it will hide the bottom image as the pixels are overwritten with new colors.

The result would look something like this, which looks a lot cleaner and more readable:

```js
// Get all your images.
var first  = document.getElementById('first');
var second = document.getElementById('second');

// get canvas and context
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var context = result.getContext('2d');

// create a counter to make sure all images are loaded before drawing
var loaded = 0;

// something to execute when loading of images has completed
function combine(){
  // The order of drawing will be the order of layers
  // The final two arguments define the size of what you want to draw
  context.drawImage(second, 0, 0, 400, 400);
  context.drawImage(first, 100, 100, 200, 200);
}

// Add event listeners to the images
first.addEventListener('load', function(){ 
  // increase the loaded number
  loaded++; 
  // hide the image
  first.style.display = 'none'; 
  // if loaded hits the total number of images, use the completion function
  if(loaded === 2) combine(); 
}, false);

// (wrince, repeat for image 2)
second.addEventListener('load', function(){
  loaded++; 
  second.style.display = 'none'; 
  if(loaded === 2) combine(); 
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <img id="first" width="400" height="400" src="http://www.deftune.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/thexx-400x400.jpg" />
     <img id="second" width="200" height="200" src="http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png" />
     <canvas id="result" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

Lastly I would like to add that your nested `onload` function could backfire on you when the second image is loaded *before* the first, which would mean that the `load` event does not get triggered anymore. Use separate onloads and count them in order to be sure the outcome is correct.

Comment: in fact you draw that image that loads first. this is unacceptable.

Comment: @Merge-pony that is simply not true. The `combine` only gets executed once both are loaded (`loaded === 2`). The order in which they are listed in that function is the order in which they are drawn, it has nothing to do with loading. I have mentioned this in the answer.

Comment: yes, I made mistake. But with images with High resolution I've got drawn only one image instead one in two. Even if I switch drawImage

Comment: This can have many reasons, the main culprit would be images overlapping. You can define the size of image to draw by passing in a third and fourth argument to the `drawImage` function to see if that is the case (aka draw the first at 400x400 and the second 200x200 to test. One image should be overlapping the other in the middle now). Check out the documentation for more on drawing images: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: thnx for your answer. but it didn't helped me